# Extension Methods on Generic Classes

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, fluent

I'm playing around with creating some fluent API's; sort of a DSL. I keep running into a specific issue, and I haven't found a way around it, here or elsewhere, that addresses the exact problem as I see it. Additionally, I've seen lots of people ask many variations of this issue.

Here's a, obviously contrived, sample of what I *want* to do...

```
Run<Car>.Off<Road>();
Run<Car>.Off<Cliff>();
Run<Person>.Off<Road>();

Person pete = new Person();
pete.Run().Off<Road>();
pete.Run().Off<Cliff>();
```

The last two lines will not compile giving an error of Unknown Method. I think I need to use extension methods to accomplish it, if it's even possible, but I have been unable to come up with a working solution.  Here is what I have so far...

```
public class Run<TActor, TTarget>
{
    public Run() { }
    public Run(TActor actor) { }
    public Run(TActor actor, TTarget target) { }

    public TActor Actor { get; set; }
    public TTarget Target { get; set; }
}

public static class Run<TActor>
{
    public static Run<TActor, TTarget> Off<TTarget>()
    {
        return new Run<TActor, TTarget>();
    }
}
```

I tried making extension methods on Run, like below, but then I run into issues with it now knowing what TActor or TTArget types are.

```
public static class RunExtensions
{
    public static TRun Run<TRun>(this TRun run) where TRun : Run<TActor, TTarget>
    {
        // doesn't compile
    }

    public static Run<TActor, TTarget> Run<TActor>(this TActor actor)
    {
        // obviously this doesn't work either
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't compile" is less useful than the actual error message provided by the compiler.

Comment: Very true. Sorry about that. The error is unknown parameter (for whichever isn't there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your extension methods are simply missing additional generic arguments that are needed:

```
public static class RunExtensions
{
    public static TRun Run<TRun, TActor, TTarget>(this TRun map) 
        where TRun : Run<TActor, TTarget>
    {
        return map;
    }

    public static Run<TActor, TTarget> Run<TActor, TTarget>(this TActor actor)
    {
        return new Run<TActor, TTarget>(actor);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. However, doing so makes the extension method unable to infer the types, producing a method call like pete.Run<Person, Road>().Off<Road>();... which totally defeats what I'm trying to do. It may be that what I want to do simply isn't possible.

Comment: @JohnKraft So where do you expect it to infer the type from?  There is no way of the method knowing what the type of the target ought to be.  It can't just pull it out of thin air.

Comment: Exactly. :) As I stated, it may not be possible, but I thought I'd ask people smarter than myself. It seems to be a rather common question, though, judging from the number of questions on Stack Overflow relating to getting the class name from an instance to pass to a generic method.